# WPF control derived from TextBox loses default margins

Tags: wpf, textbox

I have created a custom WPF control that derives from TextBox, the derived control works correctly. However, for some reason when I use my custom control by default the control doesn't stretch and doesn't have the same default margins. Whilst I can add these defaults to my custom control constructor I would like to understand how they are applied in textbox and what others am I missing. My question is if my control inherits from textbox surely it should pickup the same default values?

Comment: Perhaps if you show your code then we'll be able to work out the answer? Until then, we'd only be guessing.

Comment: Do you have any XAML for your control, or did you just create a derived class (.cs file only)?

Comment: @vesan it was just a cs file. Can upload my code but it wasn't really doing anything other than inheriting from textbox.